# Date Format examples

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, date, nsdateformatter

i want to create different methods related NSDate , eg, datedifference,date to seconds,
date comparision, date format conversion .can any one give me code or link related thos methods if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this [link1](http://www.stepcase.com/blog/2008/12/02/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/) [link2](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)